# Allow richtext commenting on blog

Tags: blogs

Is there any security issue in allowing richtext commenting on blog for public visitors?

Is there any blog system that actually supports richtext commenting?

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always allow [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) syntax. That way your users can do basic richtext formatting, but still be secure because no HTML code would be allowed.

Comment: What if i can only use richtext editor? what are the security concern of letting public visitors just enter comments using html syntax and also allowing them to be able to enter javascript content etc?

Comment: If you do not do any filtering? They can load scripts that can exploit users, they can easily create link spam, etc.. It would not be recommended at ALL to just allow them to input whatever they please.